# Какой именно тип нейронной сети подойдёт для карточной игры?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Есть готовое приложение - игра в "Подкидного дурака". Игроки подключаются к серверу, соединяются попарно, всё отлично, все работает. Клиент - винда, UWP. Сервер - .NET, крутится на Azure. Используется SignalR, для тех, кто понимает. Со всем этим проблем нет.

Чего хочется: сделать бота для игры. Не тупого, а натренировать его на манере игры игроков-победителей. На сервере есть вся информация о том, кто как ходил, отбивался, подбрасывал и кто выиграл в конце концов.

Вопрос: какой именно тип нейронной сети (ведь она мне нужна, да?) подойдёт для этой конкретной задачи? Что гуглить, куда рыть? Ну и типа road-map: сначала это прочитай, потом с этим разберись.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Начните с [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) сети, мне кажется, что это как раз ее случай.

Roadmap я бы видел так:

1. Читаем вики + [habr](https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/331310/), чтобы понять что это за зверь
2. Ищем либу реализующую LSTM на платформе .NET
3. Прикручиваем